# how to disable touch events in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

------------------------update------------------------

Now I have prevented the moving of cursor, but now how can I disable the touch event?

---

In my app, if I touch on my app, I don't want to the cursor move on where I touch, so I have to disable all the touch events, I use the eventFileter, but it doesn't work very well.

main window:

```
QQuickWindow* win = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>(engine.rootObjects()[0]);
//win->showMaximized();
gHwnd = (HWND)win->winId();
DisableTouchFeedback(gHwnd);
pObject->installEventFilter(new QTouchEventFilter);
```

Event filter:

```
class QTouchEventFilter: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:

    QTouchEventFilter(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent)
    {
    }

    protected:

    bool eventFilter(QObject * p_obj, QEvent * p_event)
    {
        if (p_event->type() == QEvent::FocusIn ||
                p_event->type() ==   QEvent::CursorChange ||
                p_event->type() == QEvent::TouchBegin ||
                p_event->type() == QEvent::TouchUpdate ||
                p_event->type() == QEvent::TouchEnd ||
                p_event->type() == QEvent::TouchCancel||
                p_event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick||
                p_event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress ||
                p_event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease ||
                p_event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove ||
                p_event->type() == QEvent::MouseTrackingChange||
                p_event->type() == QEvent::Gesture
                )

        {
            qInfo()<<"----------------------"<<p_event->type();
            p_event->ignore();
            return true;
        }
        qInfo()<<"+++++++++++++++++++"<<p_event->type();
        return false;
    }
};
```

Is there a way like set acceptTouchEvents(false) in qml?

Comment: Which OS? I don't think that is possible in QT, for at least in Windows 10 this is done by the OS - the cursor is moved upon touch, even if there is no QT application at all.

Comment: The app is on Win10,Now I have prevented the moving of cursor, but how can I disable the touch event?

Comment: I am baffled. I was so sure, `MousArea` has a property `touchEnabled`, but instead it was the [`MultiPointTouchArea`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-multipointtoucharea.html) that has the property `mouseEnabled`. Maybe it is possible to use such a `MultiPointTouchArea` to catch the touch and prevent it from interfering? I don't know your exact use-case.

Comment: Maybe you could post a feature request at http://bugrepors.qt.io to have this easier for future use.